# Select Case in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below SQL query that returns the following output for employee time ATTENDANCE.

Note when `InOut = '0'` it means in, and if `InOut = '1'` it means out.

Query:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(mi, LogTime) AS [InMin],
    OutletName as [InOutletName]
FROM 
    [dbo].[AccessLog]
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Outlets ON dbo.Outlets.OutletCode = dbo.AccessLog.TerminalID
WHERE 
    DATEPART(HOUR, LogTime) = '15'
    AND InOut = '0'
    AND CAST(LogDate AS date) = '2016-12-01'
```

Output:

```
InMin   InOutletName
--------------------
47      GJ-SH1
```

The output I am looking for in to get `OutMin, OutOutletName` and this can be applied when `InOut = '1'`

Desired output:

```
InMin   InOutletName OutMin OutOutletName
-----------------------------------------
47      GJ-SH1       10     GJ-SH1
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to write another query for the OutMin (using `InOut = '1'`) and join the two subqueries together on `outletname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get a chance to try it out in my SSMS, but required query should be something like this -

```
SELECT
    Case When InOut = '0' Then DATEPART(mi, LogTime) End AS [InMin],
    Case When InOut = '0' Then OutletName End as [InOutletName],
    Case When InOut = '1' Then DATEPART(mi, LogTime) End AS [OutMin],
    Case When InOut = '1' Then OutletName End as [OutOutletName]
FROM 
    [dbo].[AccessLog]
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Outlets ON dbo.Outlets.OutletCode = dbo.AccessLog.TerminalID
WHERE 
    DATEPART(HOUR, LogTime) = '15'
    AND CAST(LogDate AS date) = '2016-12-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to join the `AccessLog` table twice:

```
SELECT
        DATEPART(mi, ali.LogTime) AS [InMin],
        DATEPART(mi, alo.LogTime) AS [OutMin],
        OutletName as [InOutletName]
FROM dbo.Outlets
INNER JOIN [dbo].[AccessLog] ali
ON dbo.Outlets.OutletCode = ali.TerminalID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AccessLog] alo
ON dbo.Outlets.OutletCode = al0.TerminalID AND CAST(ali.LogDate AS date) = CAST(alo.LogDate AS date) AND alo.InOut = '1'
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, LogTime) = '15'
AND ali.InOut = '0'
AND CAST(ali.LogDate AS date) = '2016-12-01'
```

Note that for the `AccessLog` representing the out date I've used a `left join`, so that you will also get Outlet names that hasn't logged out yet.

Comment: thanks but i am not looking for to get "Outlet names that hasn't logged out yet"

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote it on the fly, not sure about the result but you can try it. It may help:

```
    ;with InQuery as (SELECT
    DATEPART(mi, LogTime) AS [InMin],
    OutletName as [InOutletName]
    FROM [dbo].[AccessLog]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets
    ON dbo.Outlets.OutletCode = dbo.AccessLog.TerminalID
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, LogTime) = '15'
    AND InOut = '0'
    AND CAST(LogDate AS date) = '2016-12-01'),
    OutQuery As (SELECT
    DATEPART(mi, LogTime) AS [OutMin],
    OutletName as [OutOutletName]
    FROM [dbo].[AccessLog]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets
    ON dbo.Outlets.OutletCode = dbo.AccessLog.TerminalID
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, LogTime) = '15'
    AND InOut = '1'
    AND CAST(LogDate AS date) = '2016-12-01')

    select iq.*, oq.* from InQuery iq, OutQuery oq
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: try now please. i told you, i wrote it quickly, so some commas were still there :)

Comment: hi thanks the query has no errors but it returns empty data .

Comment: are the two sqls returning data? try this: select * from InQuery select * from OutQuery instead of this (just for testing)     select iq.*, oq.* from InQuery iq, OutQuery oq

Comment: InQuery RETUNS DATA
 OutQuery dose not

Comment: are you sure that you have data with InOut = 1?? run this one seperately please and see if you get data: SELECT
    DATEPART(mi, LogTime) AS [OutMin],
    OutletName as [OutOutletName]
    FROM [dbo].[AccessLog]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets
    ON dbo.Outlets.OutletCode = dbo.AccessLog.TerminalID
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, LogTime) = '15'
    AND InOut = '1'
    AND CAST(LogDate AS date) = '2016-12-01'

Comment: i don't have data with InOut = 1